# c - Multiple select()s to monitor multiple FD_SETs

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm not an expert in Network Programming. I basically have two kinds of clients who have different time-outs. I am supposed to use UDP with connected sockets for client-server communication.

The problem is twofold:

a) I need to mark as died whichever client (alternatively, socket) does not respond for t1 seconds. Using select would time out if none of the sockets in read_fd_set have anything to read within the timeout value. So, how do I time-out any one socket which is not having data to read for quite some time?

- Currently, whenever select returns, I myself keep track of which sockets are responding and which not. And I add t1.tu_sec to the individual time elapsed of each client (socket). Then, I manually close and exclude from FD_SET the socket which does not respond for (n) * (t1.tu_sec) time. Is this a good enough approach?

b) The main problem is that there are two kinds of clients which have different time-outs, t1 and t2. How do I handle this?

- Can I have two select()s for the two kinds of clients in the same loop? Would it cause starvation without threads? Is using threads advisable (or even required) in this case?

I've been roaming around the web for ages!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: would you kindly reformat your question (i.e. paragraph breaks etc) so that it's actually readable?

Comment: Oh! I did put breaks but I was unaware of the format the website requires. Apparently simple line breaks is not good enough. Let me do the needful.

Comment: you cannot block on two select() calls at the same time. either you put all the fds into one fd_set, or you use two fd_sets, and call select on them alternatingly. (IIRC the latter technique is sometimes used to separate *fast* from *slow* fds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a special case of a very common pattern, where a select/poll loop is associated with a collection of timers.

You can use a priority queue of tasks, ordered on next (absolute) firing time; the select timeout is always then just the absolute time at the front of the queue.

- when select times out (and just before the next iteration, if your tasks may take a long time to complete), get the current time, pull every task that should already have executed off the queue, and execute it
- (some) tasks will need to be re-scheduled, so make sure they can mutate the priority queue while you do this

Then your logic is trivial:

- on read, mark the socket busy
- on timer execution, mark the socket idle

  - if it was *already* idle, that means nothing was received since the last timer expiry: it's dead

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution that comes to my mind, is to keep the sockets in a collection sorted by the time remaining until the nearest timeout.

Use `select` with the timeout set to the smallest time remaining, remove/close/delete the timed-out socket from the collection, and repeat.

So, in pseudo-code it might look like this:

```
C = collection of structs ( socket, timeout, time_remaining := timeout )

while (true) {
    sort_the_collection_by_time_remaining
    next_timeout = min(time_remaining in C)
    select ( sockets in C, next_timeout )
    update_all_time_remaining_values
    remove_from_C_if_required  //if timeout occured
}
```

Comment: just a quick optimization: it's enough to update the sockets which responded, and the head of the list (of course this only makes sense with lots of sockets)

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be solved with a single `select` call. For each socket have two values related to the timeout: The actual timeout; And the amount of time until timeout. Then count down the "time until timeout" every 0.1 second (or similar), and when it reaches zero close the socket. If the socket receives traffic before the timeout simply reset the "time until timeout" to the timeout value and start the down-count again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This is in essence pretty much what I am currently doing: to keep track of the responding and non-responding sockets myself every time select returns.
I was thinking of not having to maintain the distinction between longer-taking and short-taking sockets myself. Thanks, anyways! :)